# Change NSIS language at runtime

Tags: localization, nsis

I have specific design for my NSIS installer and the language selection should be performed in a first page. But when I change $LANGUAGE to one of existing languages the language is not changed. Could you please help me to find out if it is possible to perform such task with NSIS?

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple languages, the LangStrings are initialized by the LangDll after the `.onInit` function and depending of the `$LANGUAGE` value.

I am not sure that one can update the LangStrings later.

The standard language selection during installer startup don't suit your needs ?

Comment: No, we have totally new design. None of standard pages will be used except the INSTFILES. everything will be customized with new UI with custom created plugin. But if it turns out that what we want is not possible with NSIS, then language selection will be performed separately from .onInit because only there changes of $LANGUAGE takes effect.